# Package naming structure

Tags: scala

What does this package naming structure accomplish in a Scala file?

```
package myco.group.component
package foo
package bar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
package myco.group.component.foo.bar

import mco.group.component._
import mco.group.component.foo._
import mco.group.component.foo.bar._
```

Also the same as:

```
package myco.group.component {
    package foo {
        package bar {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no benefit whatsoever other than an alternative naming convention?

Comment: @Bob You get the imports for free.

Comment: @Bob Well, two-fold. First, as mentioned, you get the imports for free. Second, you do *not* get imports from the upper components, which prevents things like `mco.group.java` shadowing the `java` package.